# como alinhar no centro com css

Tags: html, css

Galera tenho dois `button` que estão alinhados no centro usando `display: block;`. O problema e que um fica encima do outro, para ficar um do lado do outro eu usei `display: tale-cell;` e o problema e que eles não ficam no centro.

Como faço para colocar um do lado do outro e alinhados no centro da pagina?

```css
button {
    display: table-cell;
    border:0;
    padding:10px;
    width:200px;
    height: 50px; 
    margin: 20px auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<button  type='submit'>bt1</button>

<button  type='submit'>bt2</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu resolveria assim:

```
<div class="linha">
    <div class="botoes">
        <button /> <button />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.linha { width:100%; }
.botoes { margin: 0 auto 0 auto; text-align: center;     }
```

Comment: funcionou 100%, mas teria alguma forma de resolver sem ter que criar 2 div?

Comment: Com uma única div, você pode atribuir a ela as duas classes (não recomendo), ou você pode mesclar as duas classes CSS em uma única classe.

Answer (score 3):

Outra Forma

### HTML

```
<div class="btns">
  <button  type='submit'>bt1</button>
  <button  type='submit'>bt2</button>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.btns{
  text-align: center;
}
button {
    display: inline-block;
    border:0;
    padding:10px;
    width:200px;
    height: 50px; 
    margin: 20px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: muito bom, ficou muito simples sua solução

Comment: E se precisar, dependendo do que tiver dentro do button, `vertical-align:middle` nele.